# No error when Delegate signature doesn't match

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, anonymous-function

I have the following class and delegate defined in code (many other lines snipped out for brevity).

```
Public Delegate Sub TimerCallback(canceled As Boolean)

Public Class Timer
    Implements TimerManager.ITimer

    Public Sub New(delay As Integer, callback As TimerCallback)
        mState = TimerState.Setup
        mCallback = callback
        CType(TimerManager.Instance, TimerManager.ITimerManager).RegisterTimer(Me, delay)
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I create a new instance of the timer with the following code, I do NOT get a compile error, even though the signature of the anonymous function does not match the signature of the delegate (it's missing the "canceled as boolean" param).

```
 Dim timer As New Timer(Me.CookTime, Sub()
                                         Dim cooked As FoodBase = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(SuccessfulResult), FoodBase)
                                         player.GetBackpack.AddItem(cooked)
                                     End Sub)
```

I expect to get a compile error when instantiating the timer this way, can anyone explain why It is compiling without an error?  Are there any options I can set that will cause it to produce a compile error?  I have option explicit on, option strict on, and option infer off in the project properties.  As it is, it is way too easy to forgot to include the canceled argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep. That's fine - the compiler can generate an anonymous method *knowing* the signature that is needed, and simply not use the parameters it is given. So the compiler-generated method will *have* the parameter - it *just won't use it*. You can do the same in C# using `delegate { ... }`.

Comment: Isn't the point of strongly typing the argument to TimerCallback to ensure that the method signature matches?  I could possibly see this behavior if Option Infer were set to On.  But by setting Option Infer Off I would expect the compiler to not infer anything and enforce the signature.  Do you have any solutions to the 2nd part of my question about forcing the compile to generate an error or at least a warning in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

This phenomenon is called [Relaxed Delegate Conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531336.aspx), and has slightly different behavior when Option Strict is `on` and `off`. Please follow the link for more details.

It is a feature of VB, which allows for compact code, such as this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load() Handles MyBase.Load
```

If you are not using any of the arguments, why declare them all? I personally see it as a benefit of VB, rather than a problem. If you attempt to do the same in C#, you get a compile error like this:

> No overload for 'Form1_Load' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'.

Comment: The argument is not being used in /this/ example, but it may be used in other places.  My Timer code is part of a library that other people may use in their projects.  If those users are not aware of the signature for the TimerCallback they may neglect to include it, or even know about the ability to cancel timers.

Comment: @BradleyUffner: VB gives you flexibility to declare it with parameter only where it needs the parameter. You can also handle multiple events with different signatures under one sub this way, for example, for logging purposes, or debugging. Users should read documentation before using your product. After that it's their choice whether to always specify full signature or shorten it if needed. See my edit for more info.

Comment: Thank you for the added information and the actual formal name of this feature.